# IOS Release version showing error "PlatformNotSupported" because of PCLCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.GetAlgorithm()

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.forms, maui, pcl-crypto

In MAUI project targeting iOS release with MtouchLink = SdkOnly we are seeing the error "PlatformNotSupported" for the execution of PCLCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.GetAlgorithm() at PCLCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(Byte[] keyMaterial) .

When we set the MtouchLink option to None in debug it works fine. As in release mode we need MtouchLink = SdkOnly so it gives the above error when i try to login.

We dont see this issue in our Android release builds of the same project.

We were using 2.0.147 of PCLCrypto and Updated it to latest version i.e - 2.1.40-alpha but still it didn't fixed the issue.
This used to work fine in Xamarin.forms but after migration it doesn't work on MAUI IOS release.

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
public static string EncryptAesPwd(string data)
    {
        byte[] key = CreateDerivedKey();
        ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aes = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        ICryptographicKey symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
        var bytes = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(symetricKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    private static byte[] CreateDerivedKey(int keyLengthInBytes = 32, int iterations = 1000)
    {
        string password = AppConfiguration.AuthSecretKey;
        byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(AppConfiguration.AuthSecretSalt);

        byte[] key = NetFxCrypto.DeriveBytes.GetBytes(password, salt, iterations, keyLengthInBytes, System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);
        return key;
    }
```